# How to repair a corrupt MySQL table

Tags: mysql, corrupt

When I try to add User account in phpmyadmin then this error appears:

`Index for table 'global_priv' is corrupt; try to repair it`

Comment: REPAIR TABLE 'global_priv'

Comment: Max's answer is close. It will only work if someone clicked on the MySQL tab in phpMyAdmin. It won't work from other databases. It also won't work with single quotes. See my answer for the SQL, which can be copied & pasted and will work from any database's SQL tab in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 20):

If you have this problem, phpMyAdmin will be throwing a lot of errors at the bottom of the screen. It will also be showing popup errors asking if you want to Ignore them or Ignore All of them. Ignoring them won't solve the problem, as phpMyAdmin will repeatedly continue to nag you to ignore them.

When you run into this in phpMyAdmin, click on any SQL tab & run this command:

```
repair table mysql.global_priv;
```

It will then tell you that the status is OK.

[image]

Don't use single quotes around 'global_priv' as MySQL will complain about that.

If you only run this command *before* running the repair table command, then it will show the errors which are in the table... but it won't fix them for you:

```
check table mysql.global_priv;
```

If you re-run the check table global_priv command *after* the repair table command, then it will say that the table status is OK.

[image]

Before fixing the problem, I saw 3 errors in my table using that check table command. After running the repair table & check table commands, all of the errors & warning messages disappeared!

That clears up the errors in phpMyAdmin! You ***don't*** need to reinstall XAMPP, nor mess with the file system! Simply run the 1st SQL command & it will fix the problem & remove the annoying warning messages!

Answer (score 5):

select table mysql and then type this query CHECK TABLE `global_priv`

Comment: This isn't the right answer. This will only show you what the errors are. It won't actually fix them. See my answer for the SQL, which you can copy & paste to quickly repair the database table & remove the annoying errors in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4):

MySql Error: "#1034 - Index for table 'global_priv' is corrupt; try to repair it"

**Let Repair**

**Step 1:**

Open your Xampp control panel and close the MySQL server if running.

[image: Xammp control panel]

**Step 2:**

Open your Xampp directory and find MySQL named folder in this directory.

[image: Your xampp dir]

**Step 3:**

Now find a backup named folder and open it.

[image]

**Step 4:**

Now look for a folder named MySQL select this folder and copy.

[image]

**Step 5:**

After copying MySQL folder, return to your previous MySQL directory and open DATA named folder. and paste here your copied MySQL folder.

[image]

Step 6:

Now Restart your MySQL server and open your PHPMyAdmin you will see the error is gone.

Comment: That's one way to fix it, but it's a lot of extra work... to restore the database from a backup copy. You can if you want to, but this SQL command will fix it, without needing to do any of those steps: `repair table mysql.global_priv;`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, mysql doesn't start because of this table corruption, so one cannot run any query on it.

Try to copy table files from initial backup.

Table files are \data\mysql\global_priv.*, move them aside.

Table files backup are \backup\mysql\global_priv.*, copy them to data\mysql.

This should be enough to start mysql service, but all custom global privileges will be lost.

Comment: That's one way to fix it, but it requires file system access. An alternative is to run `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` to get access to the MySQL database, through the command line interface (CLI). Then you should be able to run this command in SQL: `repair table mysql.global_priv;`

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall the XAMPP and the problem has been solved

Comment: For a fast solution next time, try running this SQL command: `repair table mysql.global_priv;`. Reinstalling XAMPP takes too much time!

Answer (score 0):

I´m using HeidiSQL.
Select mysql Database. Right Click, Click on Maintenance
Select Operation = Repair.
Click on Execute.

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just running mysql_upgrade.exe found in \xampp\mysql\bin and restarting xampp and mysql fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the link (copy then paste in the browser address bar)

   http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/database/structure&db=mysql
2. Check (tick) the box before 'global_piv' table name.
3. Scroll down and find the select (options) box 'with selected'.
4. Open options and click on 'Repair table'.

Now you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I have run following command in SQL:

> repair table mysql.global_priv;

After running this command if you get error related to db table, run following command in SQL:

> repair table mysql.db;

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494876)